# Is it possible to get vector form of characters from Font?

Tags: java, fonts

I need to get shapes of letters in vector form (points and curves) in my application. I can obtain [Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) instance easily, and it seems that [GlyphVector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html) class is able to give me the required [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). But to create [GlyphVector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/GlyphVector.html) from [Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html), I need to have some [FontRenderContex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html).

I perform this operation not while rendering something, thus I can't see the way to get that [FontRenderContex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html). Is it possible to create some default [FontRenderContex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) or bypass it?

Comment: It looks like you can create it with `new FontRenderContext(null,false,false)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Banthar - yes, seems that I am able to get something interesting from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything in your application that extends [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)? That way, you have access to the `getFontRenderContext` method.

I mean you *can* just use one of the constructors, but I saw this in the docs for [FontRenderContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html):

```
Typically, instances of FontRenderContext are obtained from a Graphics2D object.
A FontRenderContext which is directly constructed will most likely not represent
any actual graphics device, and may lead to unexpected or incorrect results.
```

Comment: Hm. That makes some sense, but exactly what would be those results? I mean, I can live with small (half-pixel) inaccuracies, but if it would lead to strange mess of connected dots, that would be not what I want.

Comment: I would imagine that if the inaccuracies were small, they'd say it slightly differently in the docs. That kind of wording makes me think that the results could be much worse.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works, but you can get the [FontRenderContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/FontRenderContext.html) from a [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object from a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) object;

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(8, 8, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = img.getGraphics();
FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
```